# Matching paragraphs below title using regex , Python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have a section that needs to be matched . 
My conditions are :
Match everything including the title. The pattern for title has been already matched by me and I need to match paragraphs starting with the word "fig" . I have done it already as well but I  noticed that it stops matching further, once it encounters a non-match .
Another condition is that if a paragraph has less than 3 words , don't match it.

Here's the sample text:

```
List of tables and figure captions:

Figure 1 shows study area and locations of borewell and surface water sampling  points. Low lying area on the western side is clearly visible.


Figure 2 displays nothing much.
no match
here


Fig.y yhth hyt htyh hyt htyh th thyt htyht thh

Table xvnm,mcxnv  bvv nd vdm v
```

There can be any number of lines between paras. What happened here is that after the line end in the paragraph starting with Figure 2 , those words did not match as they did not begin with "Fig" but the sentence after them begins with "Fig". How could I possibly match the line with `Fig.y` ??

Here's my regular expression:

```
'((?:^(?:Supp[elmntary]*\s|list\sof\s)?[^\n]*Fig[ures]*[^\n]*(?:Captions?|Legends?|Lists?)[^\n])(?:(?!^)[^\n]+|(?!\n\w+\s*\w+\s*:?\s*$)\n|Fig)*)'
```

Flags used : `re.I` , `re.M` , `re.S` **(DOTALL)**

I tried adding this up ahead :

```
(?:.*^Fig[^\n]*$){0,}
```

but this does not work as I cannot find a way to skip through the lines containing `"no match"` and `"here"`.

Help appreciated. I will be using `re.findall`.

Answer (score 1):

NEW ANSWER
It is possible I'm still not fully understanding your requirements, but I'll take another crack at it.  I assume the proper regex to capture titles can be interpolated from your original regex.

```
# Python 2.7
# Typos may exist, didn't test yet
import re

def emitRecord(matches):
  if len(matches) > 0:
    print "----- Start record -----"
    print "\n".join(matches)
    print "----- End record -----"

matches = []
seenTitle = False
titleRegex = re.compile(r'expression to capture titles here')
figureRegex = re.compile(r'^(?:fig|figure)[^a-z]', re.I)
with open('text.txt', 'r') as text:
  for line in text:
    if not line.strip(): continue
    if titleRegex.search(line):
      seenTitle = True
      emitRecord(matches)
      matches = [line.strip()]
    elif seenTitle:
      if len(line.split()) < 3: continue
      if figureRegex.search(line): matches.append(line.strip())
emitRecord(matches)
```

Comment: Sorry but this won't work for me. My text is spread out in xml. And u did not take into account the variations in title.  The above can be done simply with a regex.  Lookahead against a title is the main challenge (and one reason why there's not another answer yet)

Comment: I took another stab at it.  Apologies if I missed again - I just may not be completely understanding your use case.